# Copy auto download link in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: download, azure-data-factory

I'm dealing, with an unusual API.
You send a POST to kick off a file being compiled.
Then, send a GET with the ID (returned from the POST) and eventually it will provide you with a URL that when pasted in browser start an auto-download of an excel file.

I am using ADF, an I have everything except how to get that file into an Azure Data lake.

[image: Pipeline Pic]

The Copy activity is timing out after several hours (the file from the link will download to local in seconds) so I assume I'm either using the wrong connector or have a setting wrong.

I can't find what I'm looking for in MS documentation. Any one handled something like this?

[image: Linked Service]

[image: Dataset]

Answer (score 2):

To Copy auto download link in Azure Data Factory (ADF)and store it in ADLS follow below steps.

1. Create the HTTP linked service with Binary file format and the parameterized URL.
   [image]
2. Pass the URL in dataset parameter.
   [image]
3. In sink also Create an ADLS connector with Binary file format and pass the file name in dataset.
   [image]

**Output will be:**

[image]